# example with installation and using of 'npm'

Tags: npm-install

can someone please explain me a bit how to use, install npm from this page
https://www.npmjs.com/package/messaging-api-viber

Thank you

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing? The given package seems to be documented quite well.

Comment: should i install this on my web server?

Comment: Npm is the package manager for node.js. I'd recommend reading up about node and npm.